# ¿Cómo muestro un array en JSON en frontend?

Tags: php, html, json

Codifiqué un arreglo mediante 2 consultas en MYSQL usando la función `json_encode()` y el formato de mi arreglo quedó así:

```
    **{
    "id": "17",
    "curso": "4",
    "pregunta": "Pregunta 2 para el curso test ",
    "opciones": [{
        "id": "3",
        "curso_id": "4",
        "preg_id": "17",
        "opciones": "A1",
        "correcta": "0"
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "curso_id": "4",
        "preg_id": "17",
        "opciones": "B1",
        "correcta": "1"
    }]
}
}]**
```

Mi pregunta es, ¿Cómo mostrar la pregunta con sus respectivas funciones usando `php` y `html`, o sea en el `frontend`?

Por lo pronto he mostrado solamente la pregunta de este modo:

```
<?php foreach ($salida as $ver): ?>                 
   <input type="hidden" name="pregunta[]" id="pregunta" value="<?php echo $ver['id'];?>">               
   <h3><?php echo $ver['pregunta'];?></h3>
   <hr>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: con json_decode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que en `opciones` hay un array, tienes que abrir otro bucle para mostrar el contenido, por ejemplo:

```
$json=
    '
[{
    "id": "17",
    "curso": "4",
    "pregunta": "Pregunta 2 para el curso test ",
    "opciones": [{
        "id": "3",
        "curso_id": "4",
        "preg_id": "17",
        "opciones": "A1",
        "correcta": "0"
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "curso_id": "4",
        "preg_id": "17",
        "opciones": "B1",
        "correcta": "1"
    }]
}]    
    ';
$salida=json_decode($json,true);
$html="";
foreach ($salida as $ver) {
    $html.="$ver[pregunta]\n";
    foreach ($ver['opciones'] as $option) {
     $html.= "\t$option[id]\t$option[curso_id]\n";
    }
}
echo $html;
```

**Salida:**

```
Pregunta 2 para el curso test 
    3   4
    4   4
```

En el segundo bucle, tienes que usar `$option[clave]` para obtener los valores que te interesan, te he puesto dos como ejemplo.

---

### Alternativa

Dado que estás trabajando con un JSON, puedes evitar pasar el parámetro `TRUE` a `json_decode` y usar la sintaxis de objeto para la lectura, al menos es más elegante:

```
$salida=json_decode($json); #Aquí lo dejamos como objeto
$html="";
foreach ($salida as $ver) {
    $html.="$ver->pregunta\n";
    foreach ($ver->opciones as $option) {
     $html.= "\t$option->id\t$option->curso_id\n";
    }
}
echo $html;
```

La salida es siempre la misma.

Comment: Me ha funcionado, muchas gracias!